# UITabBarController vs UIViewController with buttons act like a tab -- Memory Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to make a custom tab bar controller by creating a view controller, then add buttons at the bottom of the screen. In this VC, I'll have reference to 4 other view controllers and switching them around when user click on the buttons. I'm not sure if this approach is causing any problem compare to using `UITabBarController`.
I need to do it this way because the middle tab button will have a 3D object in it, and I think I can't do this with default `UITabBarController`.
What I'm thinking is that this approach would lead to out of memory issue because I keep too many objects (4 view controllers) alive in memory, and each view controller has lots of image & animation in it. Not sure if this is the same as `UITabBarController` or Apple has some good way to deal with memory management here.
Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Have checked that your app is leaking memory? There is a difference between a memory leak and just using a lot of memory.

Comment: I haven't written any code for it yet, I'm just planning what to use to make sure I'm going on the rite direction. My view controllers have lots of animation, so I'm afraid that it will use lots of memory. So my question is that if the way I do is the same UITabBarController? Or UITabBarController has some good way in managing memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I think you are over-optimizing too early if this isn't even a visible problem yet. If you implement your container properly using `UIViewController Containment` ([A good guide here](http://nscookbook.com/2013/08/ios-programming-recipe-28-view-controller-containment-transitioning/)), you shouldn't have any memory issues.

Examples from that writeup:

When you are adding a child view controller (switching to a "tab"), you would do something like:

```
UIViewController *newTabViewController = [UIViewController new];

[self addChildViewController:newTabViewController];
[self.view addSubview:newTabViewController.view];
[newTabViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Then when you are transitioning FROM a tab, along with the above code to go to a new tab, you would do:

```
[oldTabViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[oldTabViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[oldTabViewController removeFromParentViewController];
```

Using the containment APIs will call all of the appropriate view lifecycle methods on the viewcontrollers being transitioned (`viewWillAppear:` `viewDidAppear:` `viewWillDisappear:` `viewDidDisappear:`)

In order to make your individual tabs more memory efficient, just make sure to do any appropriate clean-up in `viewDidDisappear:` which you can then rebuild in `viewDidAppear:`.

That said, this is unlikely to be an issue unless perhaps your individual viewcontrollers are keeping very large images in memory or something like that. You have to keep in mind that all existing containers also keep all of their viewcontrollers in memory without issue.

Comment: Thanks alot Dima, you've enlightened me